# If $X$ is a random variable on the probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$. Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X=n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables

$$P(X=n)=1-P(X\neq n)=1-P(X<n)-P(X>n)=1-P(X>n)-P(X<n)=P(X\leq n)-P(X<n)$$
Therefore, it follows $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X=n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X\leq n)- \lim_{n\to\infty} P(X<n).$$ Because of the property of CDF we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X\leq n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} F_{x}(n)=1$. I'm not sure what to do next, i.e. how to compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X<n).$ Is that limit also equal to $1$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $P[X=n]\leq P(X>n-1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$

Comment: $\sum P(X=n)) \le 1<\infty$ so $P(X=n)\to 0$.